# Store method return value in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a program that creates a game board, and uses a superclass and subclasses to generate the board. Essentially, I want to use an arrayList that stores the values returned back from the methods of the subclasses of Cell. But I cannot figure out how to do it. What I have written in the BoardGame class gives me an error, and I cannot think of another way to do this.
￼[image: GameBoard]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BoardGame {



    private Die theDie;



    BoardGame(){





    }

    void buildBoard(){

        ArrayList<Player> player;




        Cell c = new Cell();

        ArrayList<Cell>cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        cells.add(c.landOn());

    }

    void runSimulation(){

    }


     int takeTurn(String n){

         //since we don't know what we are returning yet
         return 0;


    }

     String toString(String n){


         //Since we aren't returning anything yet
         return "Nothing";


     }
}






public class Cell {

    static int landOn(){


        //Since we do not know what we are returning
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString(){



        //Since we do not know what we are returning
        return "Blank";
    }

}




public class Star extends Cell {

    int landOn(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning 
        return 5;
    }

    public String toString(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning
        return "Star: +5";
    }

}



public class Lightning extends Cell {

    int landOn(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning 
        return -5;
    }

    public String toString(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning
        return "Lightning: -5";
    }

}



public class X extends Cell {

    int landOn(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning 
        return -10;
    }

    public String toString(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning
        return "X: -10";
    }

}



public class Smiley extends Cell {

    int landOn(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning 
        return 10;
    }

    public String toString(){


        //since we do not know what we are returning
        return "Smiley: +10";
    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Side note: `landOn()` in `Cell` isn't overridden by any of the other `landOn()` methods (it's static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArrayList` is declared as a `Cell`
The return type for your methods is `int`.
Your `ArrayList`cannot store anything other then instances of the type `Cell`

To store all the return types of the methods you need an `ArrayList` of the type `Integer`

Using `int` wont work either as `int` is a primitive.

Solution:

```
ArrayList<Integer> cells = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ArrayList<Cell>` as in the code will not work, as `c.landOn()` returns an `int`. Using the `Integer` return type `ArrayList<Integer>cells` will solve that specific issue. Was that the error that you were seeing?

PS: Also remember that you can just say `ArrayList<Cell>cells = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `ArrayList<Cell>cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

BoardGame class:

```
public class BoardGame {
    public BoardGame(){
        //Get finalTreats from Cell class
        int finalTreats = this.cell.finalTreats;
        //Add finalTreats to cells ArrayList
        cells.add(finalTreats);
    }

    //Get Cell class
    Cell cell = new Cell();

    //Initialize ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> cells = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Cell class:

```
public class Cell {
    public int finalTreats;
    public int landOn(int treats){
        //Test for what it landed on based on treat amount
        switch(treats){
            //X
            case -10: finalTreats = -10;
            //Lightning
            case -5: finalTreats = -5;
            //Star
            case 5: finalTreats = 5;
            //Smiley face
            case 10: finalTreats = 10;

            //Blank
            default: return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Star class (for example):

```
public class Star extends Cell{
    public Star() {
        this.landOn(5);
    }
}
```

Make other classes like Lighting and Smiley Face the same as the Star class, but change the value of treats as needed.

Hope it helped.

Comment: That `case` statement looks like a bad idea - either each `Cell` should return an adjustment amount (which is what I assumed it was doing in the first place), or treat it as a delegate so that the cell performs the adjustment.  As it is, you're going to end up having rules in two different places.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it that way:

```
public abstract class Cell{
...
}
public class EmptyCell extends Cell{
...
}
public class Win5Treats extends Cell{
...
}
public class Lose5Treats extends Cell{
...
}
public class Win10Treats extends Cell{
...
}
public class Lose10Treats extends Cell{
...
}    
public class Start extends Cell{
...
}
public class End extends Cell{
...
}
```

And your array will be like that:

```
ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
```